# Sending intent to activity from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-intent

I have yet another question. I did some research into how to properly send an intent from a BroadcastReceiver to an activity. everyone suggests doing the following:

To construct an intent and use the context provided in the receiver to start that intent. However, I would always get an error when trying to do so saying

```
AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

So when I googled about that error, people seemed to suggest that you want to add specific flags to the intent. But even with this flags present I am getting the same error. Any help would be appreciatd.

```
Intent intentMain = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
intentMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intentMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.putExtra("com.hennessylabs.xxx.FROM", senderNum);
intent.putExtra("com.hennessylabs.xxx.MSG", message);
context.startActivity(intentMain);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to start MainActivity.class from your BroadcastReceiver.  That is fine.  Though I don't see why you have done what you did in the 2nd and 3rd lines you provided when adding flags.  Why don't you just do this:

```
intentMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

So your whole code block should look like this:

```
Intent intentMain = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
intentMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra("com.hennessylabs.xxx.FROM", senderNum);
intent.putExtra("com.hennessylabs.xxx.MSG", message);
context.startActivity(intentMain);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

and then in manifest file
in mainactivity

```
launchmode= singleTask
```

or as per your requirements, you can use some other combinations also